# PhpSpreadsheets sin composer

Tags: php, composer, librería, phpspreadsheet

¿Hay alguna forma de utilizar la librería PhpSpreadsheets sin instalarla mediante composer? La he descargado en formato zip desde GitHub y en los ejemplos que he visto en internet la importan mediante un `require_once` que apunta a una ruta que incluye **vendor/autoload.php** (archivo generado con conposer). Lo que quiero es importar los archivos necesarios directamente desde el zip que descargué. Yo uso otras librerías PHP sin necesidad de instalarlas con composer, como Dompdf y PhpExcel (esta última está muy desactualizada y sugieren usar PhpSpreadsheets). Quiero hacerlo de esta forma porque en mi PC (donde tengo Laragon instalado) no tengo internet y no puedo usar composer. Y estoy publicando esto desde la PC de un amigo. Saludos.

Comment: Supongo que usas Laravel o CodeIgniter o similares, verdad?

Comment: No, para nada, no uso frameworks de ningún tipo. Yo trabajo con código nativo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está claro lo que necesitas hacer, pero no está claro lo que has hecho ya. Por eso cuesta darte una respuesta acorde a lo que ya tienes hecho.

No obstante... Sí, puedes usar **PhpSpreadsheets** sin `composer`.

**Opción 1.** Sitúa la librería donde tengas las de más librerías y luego úsala llamándola, por ejemplo:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
```

Y todo lo que necesites usar de la librería, por ejemplo **Excel**:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

Ya puedes usarla:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet); ...
```

**Opción 2.** O también puedes llamar tu librería así:

```
$spreadsheet = require_once __DIR__.'/../Librerias/PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet.php';
```

Espero que te funcione. Yo uso esa librería en mi sitio. La instalé sin `composer`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Dentro de un rato probaré las dos opciones y te diré cual fue el resultado. Por cierto creo que no es necesario mostrar que estoy haciendo. Imagina un archivo php que solo contenga la linea que importa la librería y el código que genera un excel de pocas dimensiones (en filas y columnas) que contenga solo datos de ejemplo (nada de extraer datos de una bd). Algo tan simple como eso. El objetivo es que al ejecutar ese archivo no retorne ningun error de una clase o función inexistente. Si todo sale bien entonces agregaré más complejidad.

Comment: Por cierto probé generar un excel con la librería openpyxl de python y funcionó de maravilla, pero es un poco lento. Comparando velocidad: php retorna casi al instante el resultado de una query MySQL, y python tarda más de 1 segundo en hacer lo mismo. Si php hace algo que también hace python, entonces voto por php.